# Getting node value for data that is outside of a tag

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have an xml fragment and I want to get the value of a within a tag that is not within another tag.

```
SET @xml = '<data>
    Cat
    <type>Black</type>
    <type>Orange</type>
<type>White</type>
    </data>'



SELECT @xml.value('/data[1]', 'varchar(80)') as result
```

When I run the above I get

```
  Cat
        BlackOrangeWhite
```

What I want is just

```
  Cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text()` to select the text children of a node:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/data/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)') as result
```

This should print `Cat`.